# how to separate keys and push that keys into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one object with keys and values...can anyone help to separate the key's from that object and push that keys into an empty array.

```
example = [{
    UID: "101001"
    college_address: "Hyderabad, Malkajgiri"
    college_code: "RJC"
    college_name: "Rahul Junior College"
    course_name: "MPC"
    s_no: "1"
    total_clicks: "50"
    user_city: "Secunderabad"
    user_country: "India"
    user_mail: "rahul@inkprog.com"
    user_name: "Manohar"
    user_phone: "9638529654"
    user_type: "unknown"
}]
```

Comment: See [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const example = [
  {
    UID: "101001",
    college_address: "Hyderabad, Malkajgiri",
    college_code: "RJC",
    college_name: "Rahul Junior College",
    course_name: "MPC",
    s_no: "1",
    total_clicks: "50",
    user_city: "Secunderabad",
    user_country: "India",
    user_mail: "rahul@inkprog.com",
    user_name: "Manohar",
    user_phone: "9638529654",
    user_type: "unknown",
  }, 
];

const res = example.flatMap(Object.keys);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: You can pass `Object.keys` as a callback to flatMap directly: `example.flatMap(Object.keys)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const example = [
    {
        UID: "101001",
        college_address: "Hyderabad, Malkajgiri",
        college_code: "RJC",
        college_name: "Rahul Junior College",
        course_name: "MPC",
        s_no: "1",
        total_clicks: "50",
        user_city: "Secunderabad",
        user_country: "India",
        user_mail: "rahul@inkprog.com",
        user_name: "Manohar",
        user_phone: "9638529654",
        user_type: "unknown",
    } 
];

const keys = Object.keys(example[0]);
console.log('keys = ' + JSON.stringify(keys));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate the object and push the keys into a new array

```
   let exampleObject = {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    }
    let keys = [];
     for (let key in exampleObject) {      
         if (exampleObject .hasOwnProperty(key)) keys.push(key);
     }
    console.log(keys);
```